# CS50 More-Filters (blur) program debugging

Tags: c, debugging, math, cs50

I made every other project myself and asking only for help Chatgpt because I asked what's wrong (and without solving it) it hinted at the problems and I fixed it while asking and learning about the C language. But now, we're both stuck.

It's working yes but the CS50 tester didn't get the result what he expected so it's not. Something with the math or I don't know what I'm missing.

```
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "123 135 143\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "80 95 105\n", not "75 88 97\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel in corner
    expected "70 85 95\n", not "56 68 76\n"
```

Code:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i< height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< width; j++)
        {
            double sumRed = 0, sumGreen = 0, sumBlue = 0;
            int dec = 0;
            int fakeRow = i;
            int cycle = 1;
            double calcAv = 1;


            if (i > 0)
            {
                cycle += 1;
                dec = 1;
            }
            if (i < height - 1)
            {
                cycle += 1;
            }

            do
            {
                if (cycle == 1 && fakeRow < height - 1)
                {
                    fakeRow += 1;
                }
                calcAv += 1;
                sumRed += image[fakeRow - dec][j] .rgbtRed;
                sumGreen += image[fakeRow - dec][j].rgbtGreen;
                sumBlue += image[fakeRow - dec][j].rgbtBlue;

                if (j > 0)
                {
                    sumRed += image[fakeRow - dec][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                    sumGreen += image[fakeRow - dec][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                    sumBlue += image[fakeRow - dec][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                    calcAv += 1;
                }
                if (j < width - 1)
                {
                    sumRed += image[fakeRow - dec][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                    sumGreen += image[fakeRow - dec][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                    sumBlue += image[fakeRow - dec][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                    calcAv += 1;
                }
                dec = 0;
                cycle -= 1;
            }
            while (cycle != 0);
            BYTE averageR = (BYTE)round(sumRed / calcAv);
            BYTE averageG = (BYTE)round(sumGreen / calcAv);
            BYTE averageB = (BYTE)round(sumBlue / calcAv);

            // Update the image with the new color values
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = averageR;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = averageG;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = averageB;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As reported by @RetiredNinja, you need **two** buffers for this task. Every element of your matrix is used both as a source of a value and as a destination to store a result before the task is complete.

---

Troubled by your approach (using `fakeRow`) I distilled your code to the following, with the results reported below:

```
void blur( int height, int width ) {
    for (int i = 0; i< height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j< width; j++) {
            int dec = 0;
            int fakeRow = i;
            int cycle = 1;
            double calcAv = 1;

            if (i > 0) {
                cycle += 1;
                dec = 1;
            }
            if (i < height - 1)
                cycle += 1;

            do {
                if (cycle == 1 && fakeRow < height - 1)
                    fakeRow += 1;

                calcAv += 1;
                printf( "(%d,%d) ", fakeRow - dec, j );

                if (j > 0) {
                    printf( "(%d,%d) ", fakeRow - dec, j-1 );
                    calcAv += 1;
                }
                if (j < width - 1)
                {
                    printf( "(%d,%d) ", fakeRow - dec, j+1 );
                    calcAv += 1;
                }
                dec = 0;
                cycle -= 1;
            } while (cycle != 0);

            printf( " ... CalcAv %f\n", calcAv );
        }
    }
}

int main( void ) {
    blur( 3, 3 );

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (1,1)  ... CalcAv 5.000000
(0,1) (0,0) (0,2) (1,1) (1,0) (1,2)  ... CalcAv 7.000000
(0,2) (0,1) (1,2) (1,1)  ... CalcAv 5.000000
(0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (1,1) (2,0) (2,1)  ... CalcAv 7.000000
(0,1) (0,0) (0,2) (1,1) (1,0) (1,2) (2,1) (2,0) (2,2)  ... CalcAv 10.000000
(0,2) (0,1) (1,2) (1,1) (2,2) (2,1)  ... CalcAv 7.000000
(1,0) (1,1) (2,0) (2,1)  ... CalcAv 5.000000
(1,1) (1,0) (1,2) (2,1) (2,0) (2,2)  ... CalcAv 7.000000
(1,2) (1,1) (2,2) (2,1)  ... CalcAv 5.000000
```

Using the *unconventional* `fakeRow`, your code is correctly forming the appropriate matrix indices (to my surprise!). However, the `CalcAv` counter of elements is *off-by-one*. (A common bug and an easy fix left to you to perform.)

Comment: _"like many bosses and co-workers...."_  -- Oh no, I am not sure how to feel about this: maybe ChatGPT _can_ replace some bosses and coworkers I have known ;)

Comment: @adabsurdum ChatGPT can use the Lady Gaga excuse: "Born This Way." Bosses and coworkers can only be understood through the lenses of obstinacy and dogmatism. `:-)`